# Golang, load Windows DLL in Linux

Tags: linux, go, dll, system-calls

Our vendor provides DLL, which works on Windows. Is this possible to load custom **xxx.dll** file and use its functions in **Linux** using Go?

Like this: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/WindowsDLLs

Comment: You cannot use DLLs on Linux, they are Windows only. You could use Wine instead, it emulates Windows and can run code written for Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is "no": when you "load" a dynamic-linked library, it's not only actually loaded (as in read from the file) but *linked into* the address space of your running program — by the special means provided by the OS (on Linux-based systems, at least on x86/amd64 platforms that's an external process; on Windows, it's an in-kernel facility, AFAIK).
In other words, loading a dynamic-linked library involves quite a lot of complexity happening behind your back.

Another complication, is whether the DLL is "self-contained" in the sense it only contains "pure" functions — which only perform computations on their input data to provide their output data, — or they call out to the operating system to perform activities such as I/O on files.
The way operating systems provide ways to do these kinds of activities to the running processes are drastically different between Windows and Linux.

The last complication I can think of is dependency of this library on others.
If the library's code is written in C or C++, it quite likely depends on the C library used by the compiler which compiled the library (on Windows, it's typically that `MSVCRxx.DLL` thing). (A simple example is calling `malloc()` or `printf()` or something like this in a library's code.)

All this means that most of a DLL written on Windows for Windows depends both on Windows and the C or C++ standard library associated with the compiler used to build that library.

That's not to mention that Windows DLL uses PE (Portable Executable) format for its modules while GNU/Linux-based systems natively use the ELF format for its shared object files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid not because the windows DLLs do different kernel calls than Linux shared object, both has this fancy name for system library objects

But if you need to run a windows native app on linux I would recommend give Wine a try, I doubt it works properly, and a second worthy try is dosbox, once I doubt this works too

But there is a little hope if those DLLs are written in .net framework, you could wrap them up on a nice c# code and use mono on linux side, not sure if this enables you to import those DLLs to golang, but I don't think so either

In the and with that amount of tricks to have everything working you will get some performance issues, just saying